# Migrating hive tables to AWS - How to capture CDC for hive tables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive

I am currently writing a framework to transfer **hive tables to aws.** We can't do that in one shot. We need to it over a period of time. And so there are lots of table which needs to be in Synch with AWS and On-prem hadoop.

Tables which are small and needs truncte and load is not an issue. We have a frameowrk which daily refreshes the table using spark framework.

Problem is for huge tables, we need to append only newly **added/updated/deleted** rows to AWS. Finding a newly added is fairly simple task. However how do I get updated or deleted records.

- **40%** of our total tables are **transcation table**. so Updates and deletes are frequent.
- For other 60% tables Update/deletes are not frequent. However, sometime due to data issue, people delete the past batch and reload the data.

**My questions are**

Is there a way I can get Change data capture for hive table?
How do I figure out which records are updated/deleted in **transcational** table?
how do I figure out which records are updated/deleted in External Table?

Comment: should ask to the AWS SA and this is not code things.